# How to get average, median, mean stats from a file which has numbers in first column?

Tags: linux, unix, statistics, ubuntu-14.04

I have a file in which I have numbers in seconds like below:

```
0.01033
0.003797
0.02648
0.007583
0.007491
0.028038
0.012794
0.00524
0.019655
0.019643
0.012969
0.011087
0.044564
```

What is the best way by which I can get "average", "mean", "median", "95th percentile" and "99th percentile" from this file? I have this file in my linux box so I need some linux command by which I can get those stats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case you're not bound to any specific tool, try [GNU `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) - a nice tool for "*command-line [statistical operations](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/html_node/Available-Operations.html#Available-Operations)*" on textual files.

To get mean, median, percentile 95 and percentile 99 values for first column/field (note, fields are `TAB`-separated by default):

```
$ datamash --header-out mean 1 median 1 perc:95 1 perc:99 1  < file
mean(field-1)   median(field-1) perc:95(field-1)    perc:99(field-1)
0.016128538461538   0.012794    0.0346484   0.04258088
```

Comment: how can I install datamash in my ubuntu 14 box?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install datamash`.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package datamash` I am using ubuntu 14 as of now.

Comment: Yes, looks like it's [not present in trusty](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=datamash&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). Then you can [install from source](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/download/#source).

Comment: Isn't average the same as mean?

Comment: Btw, `datamash` also supports many other operations - all summarized nicely in `man datamash`.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the previous tool `datamash` is a very powerful tool! 
If you want a full `awk` solution:

**Average:** (variables are auto-initialized to zero by `awk`)

```
awk '{ sum += $1; n++ } END { if (n > 0) print sum / n; }'
```

or in the Shebang notation:

```
#!/bin/awk

{ sum += $2 }
END { if (NR > 0) print sum / NR }
```

**Median:**

```
#/usr/bin/env awk
{
    count[NR] = $1;
}
END {
    if (NR % 2) {
        print count[(NR + 1) / 2];
    } else {
        print (count[(NR / 2)] + count[(NR / 2) + 1]) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

You need to sort the file before using it:

```
sort -n data_file | awk -f median.awk
```

**95th Percentile:**

```
sort file -n | awk 'BEGIN{c=0} length($0){a[c]=$0;c++}END{p5=(c/100*5); p5=p5%1?int(p5)+1:p5; print a[c-p5-1]}'
```

Last but not least you can use ***Miller***
https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/tree/v4.5.0